# EF Core - can't add entity with the same related objects

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am porting app from EF 6 to EF Core 2.2. I have an object with some related objects inside, each one with database generated ID and GUID (db - postgresql).

I'm trying to create a generic method to add a whole object graph with all related objects the same way as in EF 6 - like this:

```
var res = context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
```

Before the insert, EF make temporary IDs, which will be replaced with real database IDs.

So, because inside different object I might have exactly the same objects (for better understanding, my subject area is medicine, I have several different analyzes that are performed from the same sample), in EF Core I can't add whole object graph like this - getting errors, for example:

> Key (\"ID\")=(5) already exists

But in the EF 6 version, everything used to work - all objects are inserted including inner objects with correct IDs and GUIDs, without duplicates.

In both versions, temporary IDs in the same objects are also equal, but only in EF Core version, I'm getting this error.

I have tried add attributes

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

tried changing the `DbContext`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Sample>().Property(e => e.ID).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

but neither works for me - I think the problem is not here.

Also I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#identity-resolution) article in Microsoft docs, which says

> If the graph does contain duplicates, then it will be necessary to process the graph before sending it to EF to consolidate multiple instances into one.

but I'm not sure - is this about my case?

Am I doing this wrong or is it impossible in EF Core 2.2?

Comment: I join you in this nightmare. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @CarComp, Unfortunately no

Comment: I figured it out.. The solution was to NOT SAVE THAT TYPE OF OBJECT! :)

Answer (score 0):

Magic sauce:  Create an interface and implement it on object you don't want to save on the object graph, then simply do not set that object as modified.  The paradigm that I was failing to understand was that I never really wanted to save a 'defining' object during a save when that object was being used to define the object being saved.

I save the defining objects with a separate process. Works perfectly.

```
public virtual T InsertOrUpdate(T oneObject)
    {
        T output = null;

        if (oneObject.Id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            output = this.Insert(oneObject);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
               
                _dbContext.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(oneObject, e =>
                {
                    if (e.Entry.IsKeySet)
                    {
                        // See if the entry has interface with 'StaticObject'
                        List<Type> x = e.Entry.Entity.GetType().GetInterfaces().ToList();
                        
                        if (x.Contains(typeof(IStaticObject)))
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning($"Not tracking entry {e.Entry}");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                    }

                });

                _dbContext.Entry(oneObject).State = EntityState.Modified;

                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                
                output = oneObject;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Problem updating object {oneObject.Id}");
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
    
public virtual T Insert(T oneObject)
    {
        try
        {
            _dbContext.Attach(oneObject);
            _dbContext.Entry(oneObject);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            _logger.LogError(error.Message, error);
        }

        return oneObject;
    }
```

Comment: `if (e.Entry.Entity is IStaticObject)` ?

Comment: Oh. I get it.  I just used contains. I've yet to fully trust `Is` when used on an array.